# Question about integration. Real analysis. Check proof.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

> Let $p: [a, b] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ integrable and $p(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in [a, b]$. Prove that if $\displaystyle \int\limits_{a}^{b}p(x)dx = 0$, then the set of points $x \in [a,b]$ such that $p(x) = 0$ is dense in $[a, b]$.

I proved in a previous question that $``\varphi: [a,b] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a integrable and positive function, then $\int\limits_{a}^{b}\varphi(x)dx > 0"$.

$\textbf{My idea:}$ Let $X$ the set of points $x \in [a,b]$ such that $p(x) = 0$. If $X$ not is dense in $[a, b]$, for all partitions of $[a, b]$, there exist a interval $[a_{P}, b_{P}]$ such that $p(x) > 0$ for all $x \in [a_{P}, b_{P}]$. By the previous question, $\displaystyle \int\limits_{a_{P}}^{b_{P}}p(x)dx > 0$. Therefore, $\displaystyle \int\limits_{a}^{b}p(x)dx > 0$. Contradiction!

Is a correct ideia?

Comment: Completely correct idea. Nice +1 A little observation: perhaps you should call $\;[a_p,b_p]\;$ a *subinterval* of $\;[a,b]\;$ .

Comment: Thanks @DonAntonio. Good observation, I'll use it.

Comment: p(x)=0 except on a set of measure 0.

Comment: You have already proved a deeper theorem that positive function has positive Riemann integral and as you have rightly shown the current question is a cakewalk after that. +1